# Problems with EF version after move project

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

After move my Project vs2010 ef 4 to vs 2012 ef5 , appear on my Project some problems with DataAnnotations on the models

```
[ForeignKey("StrIdDocumento")]

Can't find type or space name 'ForeignKey' [Lost using directive or assembly reference]
```

I remove the reference to EF 4, then add EF5 using nugget. But the problem persists

Note: My Project is an MVC with c# and ASP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely missing this using statement.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
```

you may want to look into using the fluent api also instead of data annotations, just a thought.

Comment: Tks for your answer. That's wath i'm missing. But I'have another problema. I'm using asp validation integrated, but after the versión upgrade there is an error asking me for ``LogOnModel`` maybe you know something about it ?

Comment: please mark as correct answer. you'll need to post more source to sort that out.